# Error when using Flask_Restful in Openshift

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, openshift, flask-restful

I'm trying to create an openshift app using Flask restful. I was able to setup my app following the instructions in openshift [website](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/python/flask.html#step1). But aside from that I want to use flask_restful.

So I created a virtualenv and pip installed flask_restful. Then using the [example](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html) from the Flask_restful website, I copied the sample code and pasted it in the flaskapp.py (see [openshift example](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/python/flask.html#step1)). I also added *Flask-RESTful==0.3.5* in the *requirements.txt*.

Then I was able to run python wsgi.py and it ran successfully locally in my machine. I was able to get the result that I'm expecting. I was kind of expecting that when I push these changes to openshift, it will run smoothly. But it didn't it gave me a **500 Internal Server Error** message.

To give you an idea, here are some of my files

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-RESTful==0.3.5:
```

**flaskapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**wsgi.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

#virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
virtenv = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR','.'), 'virtenv')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
#
# IMPORTANT: Put any additional includes below this line.  If placed above this
# line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
#
from flaskapp import app as application

#
# Below for testing only
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
    # Wait for a single request, serve it and quit.
    #httpd.handle_request()
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

**Logs:**

```
192.69.20.2 - - [30/Nov/2016:15:40:04 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 637 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
[Wed Nov 30 15:40:13 2016] [error] [client 127.5.221.1] mod_wsgi (pid=411796): Target WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/583f10ac2d5271154f00001d/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Nov 30 15:40:13 2016] [error] [client 127.5.221.1] mod_wsgi (pid=411796): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/583f10ac2d5271154f00001d/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Nov 30 15:40:13 2016] [error] [client 127.5.221.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Nov 30 15:40:13 2016] [error] [client 127.5.221.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/583f10ac2d5271154f00001d/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
[Wed Nov 30 15:40:13 2016] [error] [client 127.5.221.1]     from myapp import app as application
[Wed Nov 30 15:40:13 2016] [error] [client 127.5.221.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/583f10ac2d5271154f00001d/app-root/runtime/repo/myapp.py", line 1, in <module>
[Wed Nov 30 15:40:13 2016] [error] [client 127.5.221.1]     from flask import Flask
[Wed Nov 30 15:40:13 2016] [error] [client 127.5.221.1] ImportError: No module named flask
192.69.20.2 - - [30/Nov/2016:15:40:13 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 637 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
```

Comment: What error messages were in the logs?

Comment: I added the logs to the question.

Comment: It says no module named flask. is there something wrong in my requirement.txt or virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. I need to add flask_restful to setup.py

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='YourAppName',
      version='1.0',
      description='OpenShift App',
      author='Lance',
      author_email='example@example.com',
      url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
      install_requires=['flask_restful'],
     )
```